# Intl install using xampp - make failed

Tags: php, magento, xampp, magento2, php-5.6

I am trying to install the intl extension to set up Magento. But when I run sudo pecl install intl, I get an error saying that the make failed.

```
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
```

The error is

```
error: typedef redefinition with different types ('struct smart_str' vs 
'struct smart_str')
```

Comment: Might be an old thread, but did you find a solution?